# auto increment using 'case' in mysql

Tags: mysql, case, auto-increment, coalesce

I have a simple table in mysql that has different types of records, differentiated by a values in the column `ptype`

my table looks like this

id1...ptype..usr...item
1.....43.......2......7001
2.....44.......2......8001
3.....43.......2......7002
4.....43.......2......7003
5.....43.......3......7001

When I add a new record, I need my query to insert an auto incremented value in the `item` column, based upon `ptype` and specific to `usr`.  i.e. if i insert a new record
id1...ptype..usr...item
6.....43.......3......?

it would add 1 to the highest number existing for ptype=43 and usr=3 
id1...ptype..usr...item
6.....43.......3......7002

if we added another record for ptype=44 and usr=2
id1...ptype..usr...item
7.....44.......2......8002

i think i should do this by initially inserting the new record with `item` blank and then updating that record with information derived from the new record(i.e. @lastid) using the CASE WHEN THEN method, but it's not working.

```
SET @lastid := LAST_INSERT_ID();

SET @ptype =  (SELECT `ptype` FROM a1 WHERE `id1` = @lastid);

SET @item =  (SELECT (
CASE
when @ptype = 41 then (SELECT 1 + coalesce((SELECT max(`item`) FROM `a1` WHERE `ptype` = 41 AND `plate`=7 AND `userid` = @userid), 5000))
when @ptype = 42 then (SELECT 1 + coalesce((SELECT max(`item`) FROM `a1` WHERE `ptype` = 42 AND `plate`=7 AND `userid` = @userid), 6000))
when @ptype = 43 then (SELECT 1 + coalesce((SELECT max(`item`) FROM `a1` WHERE `ptype` = 43 AND `plate`=7 AND `userid` = @userid), 7000))
when @ptype = 44 then (SELECT 1 + coalesce((SELECT max(`item`) FROM `a1` WHERE `ptype` = 44 AND `plate`=7 AND `userid` = @userid), 8000)) 
when @ptype = 45 then (SELECT 1 + coalesce((SELECT max(`item`) FROM `a1` WHERE `ptype` = 45 AND `plate`=7 AND `userid` = @userid), 9000)) 
when @ptype = 46 then (SELECT 1 + coalesce((SELECT max(`item`) FROM `a1` WHERE `ptype` = 46 AND `plate`=7 AND `userid` = @userid), 10000)) 
ELSE 0
end) as item
from
a1 WHERE `id1` = @lastid);
```

UPDATE a1 SET `item` = @item WHERE id1 = @lastid

as is, @item is returning values of 0 initially, no matter what 'ptype' the new record has, and is incrementing by 1 for subsequent entries.... i need the first record added in each ptype to be 5001 6001, 7001, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the answer for which you didn't ask: reverse your idea by creating the rows in their own tables (with an AUTO_INCREMENT as eggyal suggested) and then move the data to this table.

And now the answer:

Your information is a bit mis-matched, which might explain the problem or just be a red herring.  For example, you don't describe what 'plate' is, but you use it in your query.  You also use @userid, which is not set in your examples.

I created a table that seemed to match your data at the top:

```
create table a1 (
  id1 int primary key auto_increment,
  ptype int,
  usr int,
  item int
);
```

Then set the variable that you seemed to want:

```
set @userid = 2;
set @ptype = 43;
```

and inserted a row:

```
insert into a1 (ptype, usr) values (@ptype, @userid);
```

pulled the id back out as you did:

```
SET @lastid := LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

Then you can get the max 'item':

```
select max(item) from a1  WHERE `ptype` = @ptype AND `usr` = @userid;
```

To handle the initial case, you wanted a default.  Since you're separating the ptypes by 1000, you can use that:

```
SELECT ifnull(max(`item`),(@ptype % 40 + 2)*1000)+1 as next
FROM `a1`
WHERE `ptype` = @ptype
AND `usr` = @userid;

+------+
| next |
+------+
| 5001 |
+------+
```

Note that this isn't thread safe, so wrap it all in a transaction/trigger.

Hope that helps.

Comment: pretty sweet answer, i wrapped it in a transaction and it works beautifully. eggyal's seems correct as well, but i don't think i can use a trigger because i have other insert statements inserting into this same table. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER biA1 BEFORE INSERT ON a1 FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.item = (
  SELECT COALESCE(MAX(item), (NEW.ptype-36)*1000) + 1
  FROM   a1
  WHERE  ptype = NEW.ptype AND plate = 7 AND userid = NEW.userid
)
```

Comment: but i don't want unique auto increment values, i want values auto-incremented by 1 starting at a base of either 5000, 6000, 7000, 8000, 9000, or 10000(depending upon the `ptype`) and unique to each `usr` #.  so, `usr` = 99 can have an `item` = 7001 and so can `usr` = 72

Comment: @NathanielBarre: my misunderstanding - see my revised answer above.

Comment: how would this code know which base level to start at for each different ptype?

Comment: @NathanielBarre: it knocks 36 off the `ptype` and multiplies by 1000.

Comment: thanks! i'm a newbie though and don't think i could use a trigger in this case because i use other insert statements on this same table(but i didn't say that, did i... sorry)